# php mysql how to organize a field to update the position

Tags: php, mysql, database

I posted another question that is similar.
So still having more problems.
This is the case, I want to be able to update the column position.
following the example below. here is before the update

```
+----+--------------+----------+
| id | question     | position |
+----+--------------+----------+
|  1 | Question 1   |        1 |
|  2 | Question 2   |        2 |
|  3 | Question 3   |        3 |
|  4 | Question 4   |        4 |
+----+--------------+----------+
```

So If I update the row id = 2 the column position from 2 to 4, I want to be organized as the following. here is after the update

```
+----+--------------+----------+
| id | question     | position |
+----+--------------+----------+ 
|  1 | Question 1   |        1 | 
|  2 | Question 2   |        4 |
|  3 | Question 3   |        2 | 
|  4 | Question 4   |        3 |
+----+--------------+----------+
```

I tried many thing and nothing works.
So if anyone could help me will be very apprecciated.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
update t join
       (select position from t where id = 2) t1
       on t.position >= t1.position
    set position = (case when id = 2 then 4 else position - 1 end)
```

That is, subtract "1" from all positions greater than the one with `id = 2`.  And set that position to "4".

Comment: I tried to change the name of my table and it keep saying position field is ambiguous, sorry I am not good with database. if the table is call massage, how the query would be. thanks